# Ruby shell command evaluation doesn't work with aliases

Tags: ruby, command-line

This works:

`%x{ ls }`

but this doesn't:

`%x{ l }` where l is an alias to ls.

Any ideas to make it work?

Comment: Aliases are defined by the session's shell, they don't exist outside of it. You can create symlinks for some commands, except those that are internal to shell. Instead, look at the alias definition for `l` and use that as your command.

Comment: I was able to access my commands; but had grown dependent to a vast set of aliases; so was finding it quite difficult to adjust. Let me check out the Session gem suggested in an answer below. But frankly, was looking for something quick and dirty to implement this.

Comment: Don't rely on aliases when you're writing code that executes sub-shells. They make your code seriously dependent on that configuration, so the code will break on other systems. Instead use the full commands always. This is a good habit to get into; Avoid customizations unless you intend to set them up on every other machine your code visits. And remember, you're not going to be the only one maintaining code you write, so one-off special commands you use won't be familiar to anyone else who has to use or maintain your code.

Comment: Thanks! thats truly something to take the pain to go back to actual commands! So, probably making a script to replace the actual commands from aliases might be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre spawning a non-interactive shell with no aliases loaded, to do that you have to

```
%x{ 
 source /file/with/your/aliases
 shopt -s expand_aliases
 l 
}
```

where '/file/with/your/aliases' is often ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to spawn an interactive shell? I was trying this i Pry also without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like the [Session gem](https://github.com/ahoward/session). The reason is that the executed sub shell is restricted and non-interactive.